# Why in a UNION query SQL is attempting to convert a varchar field to int?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Let me preface this by stating that I am new to SQL. I have to separate queries that I have made They are working just fine by themselves, but when I join them with a UNION, I get the following error message:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00-12-070-001' to data type int
```

What is peculiar about this is that I am joining two varchar fields. The first one contains GL account numbers (with numbers and dashes), while the second is for part numbers with both letters and numbers.

I have tried multiple workarounds, like using CASE as char and creating view for the individual queries and then joining them to no avail! I am stumped and I cannot figure out why MS-SQL would try to convert a varchar field to int when it is going to join it with another varchar field?

Your help here would be greatly appreciated. In wanting to keep my question simple, I omitted the details, but will gladly give you any specific information that would help you figure this one out.BTW, I am using MS-SQL 2008.

Comment: Could it be that the column order is different? Please post some code.

Comment: I believe the structure of the two queries must be the same in terms of name and type for the union to work correctly

Comment: as suggested in comment and answers, you probably have a difference in the field number/order in your 2 queries.

Comment: It's best to post your query and some sample data (or use sql fiddle), if it's too complex try and create a simple example which exhibits the same error, remove extra columns, irrelevant data etc...

Comment: Because a `varchar` column on one branch of the `UNION` corresponds to an `int` column on the other branch. Bear in mind that union is (unfortunately) defined on column positions in the result set, not on column names. Without seeing the code and (possibly) table definitions, we can't offer any more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two
>   queries by using UNION:
>
> - The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
> - The **data types must be compatible.**

Reference: [UNION (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Based on that, the following is wrong:

```
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 'a'.
```

While the following is correct, though too much...

```
SELECT 'a'
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(1),1)
```